# Is there a Schauder basis of the Banach space $l_p(l_q)$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

For Banach space $l_p(l_q)$, where $p,q\geq 1$, does the following vectors form a Schauder basis of it, say a rearrangement of all $v_{m,n}=(0,...,0,e_m,0,...)$, where $e_m$ occur in $n$th coordinate and $\{e_m\}$ is the classical unit vector basis of $l_q$?

If yes, is the basis symmetric? If not, Is there a basis for this Banach space. In addition, If $X$ has a Schauder basis, does necessarily $l_p(X)$ has a basis?

Thank you for all helps!

Comment: is $l_p(l_q)$ the space of vectors in $l_p$ with entries from $l_q$?  This is the sort of notation I'm familiar with from "noncommutative functional analysis" but I'm not sure if this is what you mean?

Comment: @Squirtle : and what norm ?

Comment: @Squirtle I think you are right. Just the complement sum of $l_q$ in $l_p$ norm. say $l_p(l_q)=\{(x_n)\in l_q^{\mathbb{N}}: \sum ||x_n||_q^p<\infty\}$ with norm $||(x_n)||=(\sum ||x_n||_q^p)^{1/p}$

Comment: $\|x\|^p = \sum_n \|x_n\|_{l^q}^p =\sum_n (\sum_k |x_{n,k}|^q)^{p/q} $ it would be easier if $p=q$ (or $ p > q$ ?)

Comment: @user1952009 In fact If $p=q$, $l_p(l_q)$ isomophic to $l_p$ itself

Comment: Yes, the basis $(v_{m,n})_{m,n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is indeed a basis for $\ell_p(\ell_q)$, but it is obviously not symmetric as for fixed $m_0$ and $n_0$ the sequences $(v_{m,n_0})_{m=1}^\infty$ and $(v_{m_0,n})_{n=1}^\infty$ are not equivalent (assuming nontrivial case $p\neq q$).